# How to specify XML namespace, schemaLocation and namespace URI using annotation using EclipseLink Moxy?

Tags: java, xml, eclipselink, xml-namespaces, moxy

I want XMl document tag as follows using EclipseLink Moxy using annotation:-

`<Document xmlns=“urn:iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08” xsi:schemaLocation=“urn”iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08 schema.xsd” xmlns:xsi=“https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”>`

I am using package-info.java as follows:-

`@XmlSchema(namespace = "usn:iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08", elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED, xmlns = {@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix="swift-pacs") })`

Whereas my java Model class has @XmlRootElement as follows:-
`XmlRootElement(name="Document", namespace="urn:iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08")`

With this i am getting output as:-

`<ns0:Document xmlns:ns0="urn:iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08" xmlns:swift-pacs="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

But i want to add **"xsi:schemaLocation=“urn”iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08 schema.xsd"** to it and want output as shown below:-

`<Document xmlns=“urn:iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08” xsi:schemaLocation=“urn”iso:std:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08 schema.xsd” xmlns:xsi=“https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”>`

How to do it? If possible can anyone suggest how to remove ns0 prefix **(ns0:Document)** before document and ns0 suffix **(xmlns:ns0)** after xmlns.